# How to get the size of a struct from a generic type when Marshal.SizeOf is obsolete?

Tags: c#

According to the [Marshal.SizeOf() MSDN docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.sizeof?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8#System_Runtime_InteropServices_Marshal_SizeOf_System_Type_):

> Warning
>
> This API is now obsolete.

What is the proper way to get the struct size without using this obsolete function? We can assume .NET Core 2.1 and C# 8.

I need to use this on a generic type, so my code reads similar to this pseudocode:

```
...<T> where T : struct
{
    ...
    // Note that T will have [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 1)]
    assert(something == Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(T)) ...)
}
```

Comment: The documentations says to use `Sizeof<T>()` instead. http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=296515

Comment: Side note: while the documentation does not put details there in the warning box itself, one can see additional details there in the signature of the method showing the Obsolete attribute with an additional text referring to `Sizeof<T>()`... ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Marshal.SizeOf<T>()`

For example:

```
struct DDType
{
    public int No1 { get; set; }
    public int No2 { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

Marshal.SizeOf<DDType>();
```